# Getting a job back home while abroad

Tags: job-search

I've been living abroad for a little over 2 years now. I want to return home to the USA but finding a job back in my hometown is somewhat difficult as my wife doesn't want me to move from her country (current residence) without a definite job lined up. My current job is programming but that has only been for the past few months (I had skills just no experience) and before that I was doing manual labor.

I want to find a job back home but I keep wondering how can I find a job back home without being physically there. I keep reading/studying/practicing different programming languages, frameworks and the like but nothing seems to satisfy without years of experience and a presence on the ground there (in my opinion). I don't know anyone personally with this situation so I can't find any possible ways to accomplish this.

If the job is in my hometown I can guarantee I have a valid address because my family can help me out till I can get a place together. The hard part is always the actual being there as I assume this situation is rare or non-existent unless the company was doing foreign/outsourced hiring from the get-go. So what can I do as far as resume and cover letter to cover this situation?

Comment: Not an answer but useful info as well: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23240/when-to-apply-for-a-new-job-while-living-abroad

Answer (score 1):

I went through over a year of job hunting from abroad in 2012-2013.  The only responses I got in that year from 300+ applications were that I would not be considerred as an international applicant.  I landed a job a month and a half after returning to Canada.  I wish you luck, it is a hard road ahead.

I would advise using your permanent address that all of your US mail is going to as your address on your resume and use a google voice or skype phone number.  Don't lie but you don't need to make it clear that you are out of country from your resume.  Once into the interview process decide if you want to make a fast trip home for the interview or try to arrange for video conferencing or telephone interviews.  In the early stages of the interview process is the time to make it clear that you are abroad but ready to repatriate at a moments notice.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one target area and make that your location on LinkedIn. Scrub your resume of any location information. Do use a US phone number in your contact information.

Don't start your cover letter or resume with a "challenge". Only mention your location when talking to an actual person via email or phone. Explain that right now you're out of country, but you are definitely planning on moving to their location within a few months. You want to convince them that a) you're awesome and they need to hire you and b) your move is a done deal and won't affect your work for them.

Also, start saving a "relocation fund" now. You will need to have money for travel for interviews, as well as for expenses (temporary housing, car, storage, movers) for the actual move. If your job search goes on for long enough, you can use those funds to cover your salary when you move in advance of actually having a job.